# Reset button working and the counters are set to 0 but when I change the page or move the phone the value returns the same as before

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I am developing a step counter app in Android Studio in Java, the counters are all working fine, I have added a button which would reset all the counters to 0, but when I click the reset button the counters are set to 0 but when I change the page or move the phone the value returns the same as before.

```
import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.Manifest;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.hardware.Sensor;
import android.hardware.SensorEvent;
import android.hardware.SensorEventListener;
import android.hardware.SensorManager;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnFailureListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnSuccessListener;
import com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView;
import com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationBarView;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.DocumentReference;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.DocumentSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.FirebaseFirestore;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;



public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements SensorEventListener {

    FirebaseAuth auth;
    TextView textViewSteps, textViewCalories, textViewMiles;
    FirebaseUser user;
    SensorManager sensorManager;
    FirebaseFirestore db;
    Button resetBtn;





    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();

        textViewSteps = findViewById(R.id.step_counter);
        textViewCalories = findViewById(R.id.calories);
        textViewMiles = findViewById(R.id.miles);
        sensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);
        resetBtn = findViewById(R.id.resetBtn);

        user = auth.getCurrentUser();
        if (user == null) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Login.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
        }

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            if (checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.BODY_SENSORS) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
                    || checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.ACTIVITY_RECOGNITION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
                    || checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.READ_CALENDAR) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.BODY_SENSORS, Manifest.permission.ACTIVITY_RECOGNITION, Manifest.permission.READ_CALENDAR}, 1);
            }
        }

        BottomNavigationView bottomNavigationView = findViewById(R.id.bottom_nav);

        bottomNavigationView.setSelectedItemId(R.id.home);

        bottomNavigationView.setOnItemSelectedListener(new NavigationBarView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem menuItem) {
                switch (menuItem.getItemId()) {
                    case R.id.home:
                        return true;
                    case R.id.health:
                        startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext()
                                , Health.class));
                        overridePendingTransition(0, 0);
                        return true;
                    case R.id.rewards:
                        startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext()
                                , Reward.class));
                        overridePendingTransition(0, 0);
                        return true;
                    case R.id.profile:
                        startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext()
                                , Profile.class));
                        overridePendingTransition(0, 0);
                        return true;

                }
                return false;
            }
        });

        resetBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                reset();
            }
        });

        
        DocumentReference countersDocRef = db.collection("CounterDetails").document(user.getUid());
        countersDocRef.get().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot) {
                if (documentSnapshot.exists()) {
                    int savedSteps = documentSnapshot.getLong("steps").intValue();
                    double savedCalories = documentSnapshot.getDouble("calories");
                    double savedMiles = documentSnapshot.getDouble("miles");
                    textViewSteps.setText(String.valueOf(savedSteps));
                    textViewCalories.setText(String.format("%.2f Kcal", savedCalories));
                    textViewMiles.setText(String.format("%.2f Miles", savedMiles));
                } else {
                  
                    reset();
                }
            }
        }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error retrieving saved data: " + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }









    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        if (requestCode == 1) {
            if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
                    && grantResults[1] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Permissions granted!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Permissions denied!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    }


    @Override
    public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
        if (event.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_STEP_COUNTER) {
            int newSteps = (int) event.values[0];
            double calories = newSteps * 0.04;
            double miles = newSteps * 0.0005;
            textViewSteps.setText(String.valueOf(newSteps));
            textViewCalories.setText(String.format("%.2f Kcal", calories));
            textViewMiles.setText(String.format("%.2f Miles", miles));

            db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
            DocumentReference countersDocRef = db.collection("CounterDetails").document(user.getUid());

            Map<String, Object> data = new HashMap<>();
            data.put("steps", newSteps);
            data.put("calories", calories);
            data.put("miles", miles);

            countersDocRef.set(data)
                    .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error Saving Data: " + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    });
        }
    }





    @Override
    public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        Sensor countSensor = sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_STEP_COUNTER);
        if (countSensor != null) {
            sensorManager.registerListener(this, countSensor, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_UI);
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Sensor not found", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
        user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
    }





    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        sensorManager.unregisterListener(this);
    }

    public void reset() {
        db.collection("CounterDetails").document(user.getUid())
                .update("steps", 0, "calories", 0, "miles", 0)
                .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Counter reset successful", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        
                        textViewSteps.setText("0");
                        textViewCalories.setText("0 Kcal");
                        textViewMiles.setText("0 Miles");
                    }
                })
                .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error resetting counter: " + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });
    }



}
```

Comment: I'd suggest adding debug points so you can see exactly where the data is being reset and what data is being sent to and returned from your other pages. I'd also add debug points to where you are displaying the data to your textboxes, so you also know what data is being pulled and where it's being pulled from for that display, wit ha focus on the "onSensorChanged" method to see the value of "event".

Comment: The TYPE_STEP_COUNTER sensor only resets on a reboot - so next time the sensor fires an event you are back to its value no matter what you stored in your DB.  From API: "and is reset to zero only on a system reboot".  To compensate you'd need to save the step value at the time of reset and then offset the "real" step value with the saved values to achieve "values since last reset button press".

Comment: @5f3bde39-70a2-4df1-afa2-47f61b isn't there another type of sensor which I could use instead.

Comment: Well you could use TYPE_STEP_DETECTOR and count the steps in your app.  But compensating for your own reset with the saved value (or a negative offset) would be straight forward.

Comment: I am already using TYPE_STEP_DETECTOR @5f3bde39-70a2-4df1-afa2-47f61b

Comment: Your posted code is using TYPE_STEP_COUNTER.

Answer (score 0):

when you change the page you are triggering the "onResume()" followed by "onSensorChanged" and this last will write the new data in the  DB, you  can try commenting "onResume()" and see if the values has changed.

Comment: If I comment it out the reset button works like before but now the value is staying the issue with this is that now the counters are not working when I move the phone.

Answer (score 0):

Changed sensor to Step Detector now it works fine.